# Past simple + present perfect: is it possible?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

Can you ask this question in English?
Did your mother have your lunch done yesterday?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think **have ... done** is a present perfect there. Rather, **done** is a synonym for **ready** and **have** is a lexical verb, not an auxiliary.

Comment: We also do not combine time references that exclude the present (e.g. yesterday) with the present perfect.

Comment: The question is grammatically correct but probably does not mean what you intend.  It means something like "Did your mother cause someone else to put together your lunch yesterday?" or "Did your mother complete your lunch yesterday?"

Comment: No, and you can't in Spanish either: ´¿Tu madre hizo hacer tu comida ayer? That does not mean anything, right? So, I am not sure where you got that idea. to have something done: have your hair cut=hacer cortar el pelo. That you can say, for example.

Comment: The idea was to mix the past with a causative sentence, but i don't know if you can use it?

Comment: Did you mother have your lunch made? [by someone else]

Answer (score 1):

> Did your mother have your lunch done yesterday?

This sentence *is* grammatically correct. However, it's ambiguous, because it's not clear whether "done" is the past participle or an adjective. It could either mean:

- > Did your mother have your lunch made yesterday?

  (i.e. "Yesterday, did your mother cause your lunch to be made?"); or
- > Did your mother have your lunch ready yesterday?

  (i.e. "Yesterday, did your mother cause your lunch to be ready?").

The former ("have [...] made") implies that somebody else made the lunch, but the mother instructed that person to make it, but the latter ("have [...] ready") implies that the mother had a more direct role (i.e. making it). The ambiguous "have [...] done" could be either.

This construction *is* possible, but try to be more specific than "done".